# Graph rewriting with one-to-many pattern matching?

Tags: graph-theory, pl.programming-languages, term-rewriting-systems

In the single-pushout approach to graph rewriting, many nodes in a pattern graph can be matched to a single node of a target graph.

My question is if there is a notion of graph rewriting where the inverse is true: that a single node in the pattern graph can match to many nodes of the target graph. For example, the pattern graph $A \rightarrow B$ should be able to match a subgraph isomorphic to $X \rightarrow Y \leftarrow Z$, with the mapping $A \mapsto \{ X, Z \}, B \mapsto \{Y$}.  I'm especially interested in a definition where $A \mapsto \{X\}, B \mapsto \{ Y\}$ would **not** be a valid match for any graph that contains $X \rightarrow Y \leftarrow Z$ as a subgraph.

As an example application, consider the problem of for-loop desugaring. This for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if ( i % 3 == 0) {
    printf("Divisible by 3\n");
    continue;
  }
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

desugars to:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    printf("Divisible by 3\n");
    i++;
    continue;
  }
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i++;
}
```

A key part of this desugaring -- that the "step" part of the for loop be inserted at the end of the loop and before every "continue" statement -- is most easily expressed as a rewrite on the control-flow graph, where that statement is inserted before every predecessor of the condition (except for before the loop runs).

Comment: I don't understand your objection. Yes, I'm doing graph rewriting. I envision the example I wrote working via a source -> AST -> CFG -> CFG -> AST -> source transformation, but right now I'm just asking about the CFG -> CFG part.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Also, you can stop talking about tree transformations; they're not relevant to the question.

Comment: From that paper: "An embedding... is a total mapping  i : M -> N" . So, no, it doesn't allow one node in the pattern to match multiple nodes of a graph. So, that paper seems irrelevant.

Comment: Hey Jimmy!!  Neat question.  :)

Comment: Best comment I could receive on this. Good to hear from you Mike! Do you theorists need graph rewriting for something?

Comment: I actually don't know about graph rewriting.  I'm familiar with string rewriting and I'm also familiar with graph automata, but I've never learned much about graph rewriting.  I want to learn more!  :)

Comment: I'm searching a bit now, but it seems that graph automata and graph rewriting automata are different things (at least I think so).  Now, I got to learn more about graph rewriting automata!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Belatedly posting this answer:

This is called set node or multi-object matching. This is implemented in tools like Henshin https://www.eclipse.org/henshin/publications.php and described informally in http://www.cs.le.ac.uk/people/rh122/papers/2006/Hec06Nutshell.pdf, see 3.2.

A more formal account is in "Formal foundation of consistent EMF model transformations by algebraic graph transformation."

Thanks to Reiko Heckel for providing me this answer 1 year ago.